# How to redirect incorrect routes to a specific page with React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to redirect specific routes to my 404 page. However, there are two cases where I'm unable to redirect successfully.

1. When a user goes to a route and adds a `/` after it (eg. `/home/` instead of `/home`). This redirects correctly, however, all CSS is lost for some reason.
2. When a user goes to a protected route and adds a `/` after it. This causes a Reference error (eg. `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`).

This is how my routes are currently setup:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <ProtectedRoute path="/protected-route" component={ProtectedRoute} />
  <Route path="/page-not-found" component={PageNotFound} />
  <Redirect from="*" to="/page-not-found" />
</Switch>
```

Comment: As per your question, the lost CSS part needs more clarification / info from your side ( are you using any pre/post processor / modules ? ). Your not found page configuration is using Redirect which seem un-necessary. You could've easily used normal Switch-Route stepper. Check this - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch

Comment: Hi @ShobhitChittora, can you clarify what you mean by pre/post processor/modules? I'm unfamiliar with those terms.

As for the Redirect, yeah, I originally used your Switch-Route example, but wanted the pathway to show up as `/page-not-found` as well. With either option, I still get the same two issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix the routing issues with these two additions:

1. Changed my CSS link from `href="css/style.css"` to `href="/css/style.css"`.
2. Added `exact` to my Routes (eg., `<Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />`.